# Office 2016 can't change or set theme font

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-word-2016

I'm experiencing a weird issue I'm hoping you can help me resolve.

I've just formatted my PC and installed a clean version of Windows 10 as well as an Office 2016 64-bit from my O365 account.

All of the Office apps gets installed without a hitch. However, when I start Word or Outlook, the default font is set to Times New Roman for all styles:

[image: Screenshot]

I thought "oh well – I'll just set a default theme". So I navigate to the "Design" tab in Word and change the default theme to, e.g., "Gallery":

[image: Set default theme]

This is where it gets funky. I can see that the colors of the theme change. 
But the font remains Times New Roman no matter what theme I select.

If I go to the "Fonts" dropdown and select another installed font set, the font in the theme still remains Times New Roman. I simply cannot change the theme font for either Word or Outlook.

I CAN however select another font as a default font from the particular programs "Options" view. But this is rather annoying and the wrong way of doing it.

I've never experienced this before. Do you guys have any idea as to what might be causing this strange issue?

I've verified that, e.g., Calibri is indeed installed on my system. A Google search didn't yield any help so I'm kinda stranded right now :)

Comment: Have you installed the latest patches for Office and its products? What about repairing the Office installation?

Comment: Word's font and styles are totally messed up all the way through Word 2019. Changing something in Styles doesn't get reflected in main document body. Style keeps on showing something different, and document, even when that is the style, shows something different.